# save EKEvent to Calendar and store event.identifier to Realm database

Tags: ios, swift, realm, eventkit, ekeventkit

I am working on a project that creates an event in calendar and saves the eventIdentifier in a Realm DB for later references:

```
 func createCal(eventName: String?, eventDate:Date?) -> String {
    var eventId = ""
    let eventStore:EKEventStore = EKEventStore()
    eventStore.requestAccess(to: .event) { (granted, error) in
        if (granted) && (error == nil) {
            //                            print("granted\(granted)")
            //                            print("error\(error)")
            
            let event:EKEvent = EKEvent(eventStore: eventStore)
            event.title = eventName
            event.startDate = eventDate
            event.endDate = event.startDate.addingTimeInterval(3600)
            let remider1 = EKAlarm(relativeOffset: -86400)
            let remider2 = EKAlarm(relativeOffset: -172800)
            event.alarms = [remider1, remider2]
            event.notes = "Eveniment autogenerat de aplicatia CARMem"
            event.calendar = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents
            do {
                try eventStore.save(event, span: .thisEvent, commit: true)
                eventId = event.eventIdentifier
   
            }catch let error as NSError {
                print("error\(error)")
            }
            print("Event Saved")
        }else{
            print("error\(String(describing: error))")
        }
    }
    return eventId
}
```

And the function is called in the realm write routine witch is attached to a button:

```
@IBAction func savePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if let currentCategory = selectedCategory.self {EKEventStore.authorizationStatus(for: .event)
       
        do {
            try realm.write{
                let newEveniment = Eveniment()
                newEveniment.title = typeTextField.text! // sa vedem
                newEveniment.date = finalDate
                let al1Input = Int(al1TextField.text ?? "30")
                let al2Input = Int(al2TextField.text ?? "15")
                newEveniment.alert1 = al1Input ?? 30
                newEveniment.alert2 = al2Input ?? 15
                newEveniment.calendarID = createCal(eventName: typeTextField.text, eventDate: finalDate)
                print("event salavat in db:\(newEveniment.calendarID)")
                currentCategory.sofetEveniment.append(newEveniment)
                realm.add(newEveniment)
            }
        }catch{
            print("Eroare la salvarea evenimentului \(error)")
        }           
    }
```

For the life of me, i dont't understand why the eventId var that is returned is nil.
I have tried countless solutions found on stack-overflow but nothing seems to work.

Any help/pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the EKEvent identifier when you actually save the event to calendar.

For example:

```
public func eventEditViewController(_ controller: EKEventEditViewController, didCompleteWith action: EKEventEditViewAction) {
   controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
   switch action {
   case .saved:
      print("Event created: \(controller.event?.eventIdentifier)")
      break
   default:
      break
    }
 }
```